Hartshorne exercise II.7.13: how to define the morphism $\varphi_a$?
$\DeclareMathOperator\Proj{Proj}$
$\DeclareMathOperator\Spec{Spec}$

$C=\Proj k[x,y,z]/(y^2z=x^3+x^2z)$. $P=[0,0,1]$. I don't understand the behavior of $\varphi_a$ near $P$.
The isomorphism $\mathbb{G}_{m,k}\cong C-P$ is defined by $\lambda\in k^*\mapsto[\lambda-1,\lambda+1,\frac{(\lambda-1)^3}{4\lambda}]$
$a\in k^*$ acts by multiplication on $C-P$.
If $\exists\varphi_a:C\to C$ extending $C-P\xrightarrow{\cdot a}C-P$, then we must have $\varphi_a(P)=P$, $\varphi_{a,P}:\mathcal{O}_{C,P}\to\mathcal{O}_{C,P}$
Consider the chart $P\in D_+(z)=\Spec k[X,Y]/(Y^2=X^3+X^2)$, $\lambda\in k^*\mapsto(X=\frac{4\lambda}{(\lambda-1)^2},Y=\frac{4\lambda(\lambda+1)}{(\lambda-1)^3})$, $\lambda=\frac{Y+X}{Y-X}$
Now after $\lambda\mapsto a\lambda$, we obtain $(X,Y)\mapsto(X',Y')$, where $X'=\frac{4a\lambda}{(a\lambda-1)^2}=\frac{4a(Y^2-X^2)}{\big(a(Y+X)-(Y-X)\big)^2},Y'=\frac{4a\lambda(a\lambda+1)}{(a\lambda-1)^3}=\frac{4a(Y^2-X^2)\big(a(Y+X)+(Y-X)\big)}{\big(a(Y+X)-(Y-X)\big)^3}$
It seems that we must have $\varphi_{a,P}(X)=X',\varphi_{a,P}(Y)=Y'$. But I don't see why $X',Y'$ lies in the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{C,P}=k[X,Y]_{(X,Y)}/(Y^2=X^3+X^2)$, as their denominators all lie in $(X,Y)$. $(Y^2-X^2=X^3$ may help, but there are $Y$ in the denominator)

This following calculation shows that $X',Y'$ indeed lie in the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{C,P}$. (Hence $\varphi_a$ extends to a neighborhood of $P$.)
Recall that $k[X,Y]/(Y^2=X^3+X^2)=k[T^2-1,T(T^2-1)]=k+(T^2-1)k[T]$ via $X=T^2-1,Y=T(T^2-1)$. The ideal $(X,Y)$ is exactly $(T^2-1)k[T]$.
Now $X'=\frac{4a(Y^2-X^2)}{\big(a(Y+X)-(Y-X)\big)^2}=\frac{4aX^3}{\big(a(Y+X)-(Y-X)\big)^2}=\frac{4a(T^2-1)^3}{\big(((a-1)T+(a+1))\cdot(T^2-1)\big)^2}$
$=\frac{4a(T^2-1)}{\big((a-1)T+(a+1)\big)^2}=\frac{4a(T^2-1)(cT+d)}{\big((a-1)T+(a+1)\big)^2\cdot(cT+d)}\in\mathcal{O}_{C,P}$,
where $c,d\in k$ s.t. the denominator is of the form $1+(T^2-1)\cdot f(T)$
($c=\frac{1}{8a^2}+\frac{1}{8}$, $d=\frac{1}{8a^2}-\frac{1}{8}$. Note that $\mathrm{char}(k)\neq2$ and $a\in k^*$).
The calculation for $Y'$ is similar.
